# Cross Domain Authentication Sessions

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, cross-domain

I make a call to domainwithl4.com/account/login via ajax post from shopifydomain.com.

In the console for shopifydomain.com, it shows that I logged in and grabbed the user object.

When I go to domainwithl4.com the Auth does not seem to persist.

Is there any setting I need to turn on in order to enable this? Or do I need a better method of logging in? I basically need to login @shopifydomain.com, if successful, I make the ajax post to domainwithl4.com/account/login in order to login there as well.